# Can I load a Twig template based on the request language?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In a recent multi-language project I use Twig to store email templates for different languages. Currently I name the templates with their respective language in the filename (e.g. `email_en.txt.twig` and load those by concatenation in my controller (example adapted from the [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/email.html#sending-emails)):

```
public function indexAction($name, Request $request)
{
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('Hello Email')
        ->setFrom('send@example.com')
        ->setTo('recipient@example.com')
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                'HelloBundle:Hello:email_" . $request->getLocale() . ".txt.twig',
                array('name' => $name)
            )
        )
    ;
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

    return $this->render(...);
}
```

Now I know I could use a dedicated service or a factory to handle that kind of logic in a more saner way, but I'm keen to find out if this problem has already been tackled by somebody and how it was solved.

[edit] To avoid having this question closed I'll rephrase my question (hopefully to the better). Is it possible to render a twig template based on the request language without using an if-chain or a factory (by some kind of black twig/symfony/configuration/convention/whatever magic)?

Comment: There is no specific programming problem..

Answer (score 2):

Use an [event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html) for `kernel.view` ( [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#component-http-kernel-kernel-view) ) and change the returned template in there.

You can find some inspiration in FOSUserBundle's [ViewResponseListener](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/EventListener/ViewResponseListener.php).

Comment: Seems like a good idea at first, but after rendering the template I don't want to leave the request but use the rendered template (see the updated example in the question).